# Create camera detect object

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-firebase

I want create in Nativescript a camera with detecting objects on live and get coordinates. I read about plugin firebase, but i don't have find nothing for detecting objects.

Answer (score 0):

research this libraries how does works

```
https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/
https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html
```